# Establish values of $k$ such that the function $f$ is a density function

Tags: probability

Establish values of $k$ such that the function $f(x)=\sqrt{ke^{-k^2x^2-2kx-1}}$ is a density function

**My work:**

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=\sqrt{ke^{-k^2x^2-2kx-1}}$

We know $f$ is a density function if:

1)$f(x)\geq 0 \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$
2)$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(x)dx=1$

Well i'm trying to find the values of $k$ such that

$1=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\sqrt{ke^{-k^2x^2-2kx-1}}dx$ but i'm too suck. can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1 =\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sqrt{k e^{-k^2 x^2 - 2kx -1}} \, dx = \sqrt{k}\int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{-\frac 12 (k^2 x^2 + 2kx +1)} \, dx =\sqrt{k}\int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{-\frac 12 (kx+1)^2} \, dx = {\frac{\sqrt{k}}{k}\int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{-\frac 12u^2} \, du}=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}k} $$ where I used $u=kx+1$ and $$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{-\frac 12u^2} \, du= \sqrt{ 2\pi}$$ so $$k = 2\pi.$$

Comment: i don't have clear this step $\int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{-\frac 12u^2} \, du= \sqrt{ 2\pi}$. i think is because $X$ is normal distribution but i'm not sure. thanks for answer

Comment: Yes, notice that $f(x) = \sqrt{ke^{-kx^2-2kx-1}} = \sqrt k \exp \left({{-\frac{(x+\frac 1k)^2}{2/k^2}}} \right)$ so $X$ is normal with a mean of $-1/k$ and a variance of $1/k^2$.

Comment: If you're confused by the evaluation of the integral, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral . Alternatively, you know that the density function of a normal distribution is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$, so $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} \, dx =\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}$. Simply plug in $\mu = -1/k$ and $\sigma^2=1/k^2$ to obtain the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$\sqrt{k e^{-k^2 x^2 - 2kx -1}} = \sqrt{k} e^{-\frac{k^2}{2} (x+\frac{1}{k})^2}$$

Hint 2:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x-\mu)^2} \, dx = \sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}, \qquad \text{for any $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma^2 > 0$}$$